# Timestamp to human readable date with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

Is there a built in filter in angular to convert my unix timestamp to a human readable date format?

I have tried the following:

```
{{ ::time | date:"medium" }}
```

But it gives wrong results:

```
1232346882 gives Jan 15, 1970 7:19:06 AM
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert seconds to milliseconds... Try it with `1232346882000`.

```
{{ 1232346882000 | date:"medium" }}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uLLrs7rk/)